# What is the best way to rotate or animate these three boxes one position more in a circle width Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

See my Code here https://jsfiddle.net/js2x07m3/26/

**I want to rotate these three boxes** by clicking on one side. If I click on the right side of the area, the right box should rotate to the position of the middle box and the middle box rotate to the position of the left box. So these **three boxes should move in a circle pattern**.When I click on the left side the left box should move to the middle and so forth. My goal is a Gallery of pictures.

My first thought was something like this. The code should find the box on the left or on the right and animate their later. But one of the problems is, that $( "div[left='10%']")doesn't work and I don't know some other opportunities :/

```
function clickLeft(){
$( "div[left='10%']").animate();
$( "div[left='40%']").animate();
$( "div[left='80%']").animate();
};

function clickRight(){

$( "div[left='10%']").animate();
$( "div[left='40%']").animate();
$( "div[left='80%']").animate();

};
```

**What is the best way to let move the boxes and how can I do this?** Should I use Jquery or something other? Or do you know a similar example of this? I don't know the right way to code this.

Comment: Look at on this carousel https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel . You can try change this or use this one for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can use **OWL Carousel** plugin, and it is enough. Here are the necessary components.

At **Head**, Include the necessary style sheet and java scripts.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

**Custom CSS**, to enhance the look (Optional), and you can do more with your imagination / Design requirements.

```
.owl-item>div {
   cursor: pointer;
   margin: 6% 8%;
   transition: margin 0.4s ease;
}

.owl-item.center>div {
   cursor: auto;
   margin: 0;
}

.owl-item:not(.center)>div:hover {
   opacity: .75;
}
```

**DOM Events**, with the help of javascript, you can **initilize** and customize the behaviour based on events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $owl = $('.owl-carousel');

   $owl.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr('data-position', index); // NB: .attr() instead of .data()
   });

   $owl.owlCarousel({
      center: true,
      loop: true,
      items: 5, // Number of columns to show
      margin:20
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.owl-item>div', function() {
      $owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', $(this).data('position'));
   });
});
```

And finally, here is the **complete HTML file** for your convenience.,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
        .owl-item>div {
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 6% 8%;
            transition: margin 0.4s ease;
        }

        .owl-item.center>div {
            cursor: auto;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .owl-item:not(.center)>div:hover {
            opacity: .75;
        }

    </style>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
              <div class="owl-carousel ">
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:#000;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">1</div>
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:blue;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">2</div>
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:red;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">3</div>
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:orange;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">4</div>
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:pink;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">5</div>
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:red;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">6</div>
            <div style="width: 50px;height:50px;background:green;color:#fff;font-size: 15px; ">7</div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $owl = $('.owl-carousel');

            $owl.children().each(function(index) {
                $(this).attr('data-position', index); // NB: .attr() instead of .data()
            });

            $owl.owlCarousel({
                center: true,
                loop: true,
                items: 5,
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.owl-item>div', function() {
                $owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', $(this).data('position'));
            });
        });

    </script>

    </html>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/js2x07m3/69/) is the Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. Although this will only work with 3 divs.

```
<div id="area">
 <div id="box1" class="first"></div>
 <div id="box2" class="second"></div>
 <div id="box3" class="third"></div>
</div>
<button id="left">
Rotate Left
</button><br/>
<button id="right">
Rotate Right
</button>
```

### CSS

```
#area{
  position:relative;
  width:90vw;
  height:90vh;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#box1{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:blue;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.first{
  top:40%;
  left:40%;
  width:20%;
  height:40%;
}
#box2{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.second{
  top:20%;
  width:10%;
  height:20%;
}
#box3{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.third{
  top:20%;
  left:80%;
  width:10%;
  height:20%;
}
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#left").click(function(){
  $("#box1").removeAttr("class").addClass("second");
  $("#box2").removeAttr("class").addClass("third");
  $("#box3").removeAttr("class").addClass("first");
 });
 $("#right").click(function(){
  $("#box1").removeAttr("class").addClass("third");
  $("#box2").removeAttr("class").addClass("first");
  $("#box3").removeAttr("class").addClass("second");
 });
});
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/js2x07m3/51/).